# Kernel of $GL(n, \mathbb{Z}) \to GL(n, \mathbb{Z}_{m})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I need to describe the kernel of the canonical group homomorphism $GL(n, \mathbb{Z}) \to GL(n, \mathbb{Z}_{m})$.

Generally speaking, the kernel would be the set of all matrices in $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ whose entries along the main diagonal modulo $m$ would equal 1, with all other entries modulo $m$ equaling zero. For example, in the case where $n = 2$, the kernel of this homomorphism would be the set of all $A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ such that $\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} \mod m = 1 && a_{12} \mod m = 0 \\  a_{21} \mod m = 0 & &a_{22}\mod m = 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Is this all there is to this problem? Or is there something additional that I need to prove? It is an exercise in a section on Ideals and Isomorphism Theorems for Rings, so I thought it was kind of weird that I was able to come up with a solution to this problem that has nothing to do with ideals or ring isomorphisms. Therefore, I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: So, how do the entries look like?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp er...didn't I say that?

Comment: No, you didn't. You wrote what they have to satisfy, but not how they look like.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp the entries in the matrices in the kernel are such that in row $i$ and column $j$, when $i=j$, the entries equal $1 \mod m$, and when $i \neq j$, the entries equal $0 \mod m$. What they look like is just integers. I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're asking me.

Comment: You're right that the desired matrices must be matrices of the form $I + mX$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. What Friedrich is pointing out that this is not a complete answer to the question, because it doesn't answer the question of which values of $X$ are possible.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan oooh. You mean $X = GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @ALannister: that is not correct. For example, $X$ may be equal to $0$. The question to be answered is what values of $X$ satisfy $\det (I + mX) = \pm 1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan but the domain is $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @ALannister: yes, that means that $I + mX \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, but the question is what condition this places on $X$, which right now just some matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't know the answer to that. If you do, please answer below.

Comment: It's not an easy question to answer, so it's quite possible that what you wrote is all that was intended. The ring involved here is $\mathbb{Z}$, by the way, and the ideal is $m\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan we definitely don't want the determinant of any matrix $A = I + mX$ to be equal to $0$....

Comment: @QiaochuYuan how would I incorporate what the ring involved here and the ideal into my answer? Or do I need to?

Comment: It has to be $\pm 1$, as already noted.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I know that, but I was thinking what the set $X$ has to be in order to make that the case.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of this homomorphism consists of

$ 
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}  \dots a_{1n} 
\\
\vdots \, \, \ddots  \, \, \vdots
\\
a_{n1} \, \dots \, a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix} \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})
\end{align}$

such that

$
\begin{cases}
a_{ij} \equiv 0 \, mod \, m \, \, if \, \, i \neq j
\\
a_{ij} \equiv 1 \, mod \, m \, \, if \, \, i = j
\end{cases}
$

By the first isomorphism theorem for groups, the kernel of this homomorphism is a normal subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: This is not right. $\text{GL}_n(\Bbb Z)$ isn’t a ring.

Comment: How does this fail to be a ring?

Comment: Never mind, I see the zero matrix is not in $GL(n, \mathbb{Z}$.